# How do you change the stacking order of window items in a canvas?

Tags: tkinter, canvas, window, focus, python-3.9

I am trying to make a windows 10 simulation in a canvas of a Tkinter window (ambitious I know) and obviously I need a way to focus the simulated windows (which are ironically canvas window items) when they're selected (put them on top of eachother). There aren't many relevant questions or tutorials in the internet so I had to guess. My first attempt was to do `canvas.tag_raise(window, 'all')`, but that didn't do anything and that made sense when I read the official documentation.

> This method [ tag_raise(tagOrId, aboveThis) ] does not affect canvas window items. **To change a window item's stacking order, use a lower or lift method on the window.** [https://tkdocs.com/shipman/canvas-methods.html]

What I understood from this quote was that you need to do something like `window.lift()`, but it didn't work as I got this error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lift'`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to make it work?

Edit: now I know that you need to reference the window itself, but I don't know how that could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `lift` on the window itself, not the canvas id. Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="bisque")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def focus_win(event):
    event.widget.lift()

for n, color in enumerate(("black", "red", "orange", "green", "blue", "white")):
    win = tk.Frame(canvas, background=color, width=100, height=100)
    x = 50 + n*20
    y = 50 + n*20
    canvas.create_window(x, y, window=win)
    win.bind("<1>", focus_win)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: do I have to use .bind() to do this? because i want to make it so if you click a menu command (not the window itself) it focuses the window

Comment: @danielshmaniel: No, you do not have to use bind. You just need a reference to the window itself, which you can get in several ways.

Comment: can you give me an example without the bind method please? would be appreciated