# How to raise a canvas item above a canvas window item

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, raise

There is a solution for raising canvas windows over other canvas windows: [How do you change the stacking order of window items in a canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71839674/how-do-you-change-the-stacking-order-of-window-items-in-a-canvas)
But I am not able to raise a not-canvas-window item (for example a canvas rectangle) above a canvas window item.
How can I do this?

Here is an example code where I try to raise the rectangle above a canvas window (the example was copied from the link above and extended by a canvas rectangle):

```
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="bisque")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def focus_win(event):
    event.widget.lift()

for n, color in enumerate(("black", "red", "orange", "green", "blue", "white")):
    win = tk.Frame(canvas, background=color, width=100, height=100)
    x = 50 + n*20
    y = 50 + n*20
    canvas.create_window(x, y, window=win)
    win.bind("<1>", focus_win)
rec = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+100, y+100)
canvas.tag_raise(rec, "all")


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am not able to raise a not-canvas-window item (for example a
> canvas rectangle) above a canvas window item. How can I do this?

**You can't**. The [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.html#M15) says:

> The items in a canvas are ordered for purposes of display, with the
> first item in the display list being displayed first, followed by the
> next item in the list, and so on. Items later in the display list
> obscure those that are earlier in the display list and are sometimes
> referred to as being “on top” of earlier items. When a new item is
> created it is placed at the end of the display list, on top of
> everything else. Widget commands may be used to re-arrange the order
> of the display list.
>
> **Window items are an exception to the above rules. The underlying
> window systems require them always to be drawn on top of other items.**
> In addition, the stacking order of window items is not affected by any
> of the canvas widget commands; you must use the Tk raise command and
> lower command instead.

Or **can you ?**

I mean you always could **have multiple canvases as window-items** and draw what ever you want to in those canvases.